# How can I fix this really simple .NET code using Generics to return the strongly typed result?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, contravariance

NOTE: All of the code below [exists in this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5WB7hE).

I'm having trouble (again) trying to grok Generics/covariance/contravariance. :(

It's so killing me - so please be kind to me.

So, I have this fictitious pet shop and I'm trying to easily **search for a Pet in our pet-inventory**.

The main search class `SearchMagic` is where all my greif is. I'm trying to say the following:

`var pet = searchMagic.SearchForAPet("Fido");` and it will .. in this case return a `Dog` which is Fido.

Now the kicker is how I've implemented the class `SearchMagic`. This is where it has the smarts to search for `Cat`'s first, then `Dog`'s. The problem is, I just can't seem to figure out a way to return the cat or dog instance, if one was found. It keeps complaining about `Cannot implicitly convert...`

I keep trying to say to the code: **At the very least, I need a `SearchResult<IAnimal>` returned. So if that's a concrete `Cat` or `Dog`, then awesome-sauce. Otherwise, null**. And then for the code that *calls* that method and gets the returned result, the only things I can *do* on that result, are anything defined in `SearchResult<IAnimal>`. So if my `Cat` instance has some cat specific properties or methods, then bad luck, I can't call them on the `result` because the result is an `SearchResult<IAnimal>` and only the `IAnimal` stuff is exposed.

Here's the code, with some comments INLINE to show where the error occurs...

#### Show me ze code, please.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        var searchMagic = new SearchMagic();

        var animal = searchMagic.SearchForAPet("Fido");
    }


    // ***********************************
    // ** Interfaces / contracts        **
    // ***********************************


    public interface IAnimal
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISearchService<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
    {
        SearchResult<TAnimal> SearchInventory(string query);
    }

    public class SearchResult<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
    {
        TAnimal Pet { get; set; }
        decimal Price { get; set; }
    }


    // ***********************************
    // ** Concrete implementations      **
    // ***********************************

    public class Cat : IAnimal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dog : IAnimal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CatSearchService : ISearchService<Cat>
    {
        public SearchResult<Cat> SearchInventory(string query)
        {
            return new SearchResult<Cat>();
        }
    }

    public class DogSearchService : ISearchService<Dog>
    {
        public SearchResult<Dog> SearchInventory(string query)
        {
            return new SearchResult<Dog>();
        }
    }

    public class SearchMagic
    {
        private CatSearchService _catSearchService = new CatSearchService();
        private DogSearchService _dogSearchService = new DogSearchService();

        public SearchResult<IAnimal> SearchForAPet(string query)
        {
            var cat = _catSearchService.SearchInventory(query);
            if (cat != null)
            {
                // ** ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.SearchResult<Program.Cat>' to 'Program.SearchResult<Program.IAnimal>'
                return cat;
            }

            var dog = _dogSearchService.SearchInventory(query);
            if (dog != null)
            {
                // ** ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.SearchResult<Program.Dog>' to 'Program.SearchResult<Program.IAnimal>'  
                return dog;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: May I know whats the database underneath you're planning to use?

Comment: It's 100000% irrelevant and has nothing to do with the problem. Please don't suggest use ES/Lucene/DocDb, etc... I know how to do all that. I made this simplistic scenario to help define my `generics` problem.

Comment: Sorry for asking, a mongodb fan here, ran into this problem before. 

Your ISearchService<TAnimal> implementations seems to implement the `SearchInventory` method with Concrete implementations. Can you keep those as a `SearchResult<IAnimal>` instead of `SearchResult<Cat>` ?

Comment: No - because at some point, my specific search services (that cat/dog ones) need to be tightly coupled to a `Cat` or `Dog` so it "knows what to do".

Comment: Understood, trying something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's one way of doing it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KI3f6i).

If you want your `SearchForAPet` method to be able to return a "search result" that could either be a "dog search result" or a "cat search result", it needs to return a covariant interface, not a concrete type:

```
public interface ISearchResult<out TAnimal> where TAnimal: IAnimal
{
    TAnimal Pet { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }
}

public class SearchResult<TAnimal> : ISearchResult<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
{
    public TAnimal Pet { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

...

public ISearchResult<IAnimal> SearchForAPet(string query)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok sweet. Why? What does the `out` do that suddenly makes this work? (Sorry for the lame question) :(

Comment: The `out` says you can only get the `IAnimal` "out" via the interface, not put one "in". Otherwise your concrete class could be a "dog search result", but since you only know it is an "animal search result" you could try to stick a cat in it wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any other way to do this keeping the structure intact either. You'd need  something like the following to get your SearchResult derived from :

```
public interface ISearchResult<out TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
{
    TAnimal Pet { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }
}
```

In any case if you want to opt out of the `out` you'd need to cast that accordingly while doing the return.

Reason being:

It looks like another classic covariance, contravariance and invariance issue here. According to the [doc here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) you can go convariant that would enable you to use a more derived type than originally specified and vice versa with contravariance but you can't possibly expect to do this:

```
public class Program
{      
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Derived> dlist = new List<Derived>();
        List<Base> bIEnum = dlist;
    }
}
```

But this you can:

```
public class Program
{  
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Derived> dlist = new List<Derived>();
        IEnumerable<Base> bIEnum = dlist;
    }
}
```

Thus having a ISearchResult or ISearchResult is your best bet here